# librosa error -> AttributeError: module 'librosa.display' has no attribute 'waveplot'

Tags: python, librosa

[ss of the error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00Rbx.png)

I tried to use this code :

```
!pip install --upgrade librosa
```

But it still gives me the same error. How can I fix this, anybody can help me?

Comment: You need to use ```librosa.display.waveshow(data, sample_rate)``` to display the plot..

Answer (score 8):

Try this,

```
librosa.display.waveshow(data, sr=sampling_rate)
```

Answer (score 1):

### In the latest version of librosa, `waveplot` has been replaced with `waveshow`.

But this exact error persists even with the latest versions of `librosa` and `matplotlib`. This small hack will resolve the issue. Just add color as a parameter and it'll not throw this error anymore:

```
librosa.display.waveshow(y, sr=sr, color="red")
```